# Android Studio Kotlin error with dataSnapshot.getValue

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

i've converted a java file to kotlin file in a recent project, the problem is that i'm facing an error with this code:

```
 val map = dataSnapshot.getValue<Map<*, *>>(Map<*, *>::class.java)
```

I'm having a red line under "Map<*, *>::class", and android studio says:

> Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

What should i do with this code? is there is any other way to write it?

Here is a relative kotlin code snippet:

```
val messageText = messageArea!!.text.toString()
        if (messageText != "") {
            val map = HashMap<String, String>()
            map.put("message", messageText)
            map.put("user", UserDetails.username)
            reference1!!.push().setValue(map)
            reference2!!.push().setValue(map)
            messageArea!!.setText("")
        }
    }
    reference1!!.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, s: String) {
            val map = dataSnapshot.getValue<Map<*, *>>(Map<*, *>::class.java)
            val message = map.get("message").toString()
            val userName = map.get("user").toString()
```

Original java code snippet:

```
String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();

            if(!messageText.equals("")){
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("message", messageText);
                map.put("user", UserDetails.username);
                reference1.push().setValue(map);
                reference2.push().setValue(map);
                messageArea.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            String message = map.get("message").toString();
            String userName = map.get("user").toString();
```

Comment: could you post the original java code?

Comment: I've edited the post with java code.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122450/how-to-get-generic-parameter-class-in-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks alot guys, probelm resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try casting it.

```
val map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map::class.java) as Map<String, String>
```

You may want to suppress warnings for "Unchecked Cast", but that is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122450/how-to-get-generic-parameter-class-in-kotlin) you have the option to use Kotlin's [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) feature and implement something like this to extend DataSnapshot.

```
inline fun <reified T> DataSnapshot.getValue(): T? {
    return getValue(T::java.class)
}
```

Or based on Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()) of DataSnapshot you can get the map value like this.

```
val map = dataSnapshot.getValue()
if (map is Map<*, *>) {
    val message = map["message"].toString()
    val userName = map["user"].toString()
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me in Kotlin when trying to cast `snapshot.value` into a Kotlin `map`