# Kotlin get class name of a class pass-in to generic class

Tags: class, kotlin, oop, generics

I want to get the class name of the class pass-in into a generic class

```
class GernericClass<T> {
  fun printOut() {
    println(T::class.java.name) // I want something like this

  }
}
```

This is my main function

```
fun main() {
  val className = GernericClass<SomeObjectClass>()
  className.printOut() // wanted output: SomeObjectClass
}
```

Is it possible to get the class name only by calling `GernericClass<SomeObjectClass>()`

Comment: Probably, this question is a duplicate of this one; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122450/how-to-get-generic-parameter-class-in-kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get generic parameter class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122450/how-to-get-generic-parameter-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Need a subclass to specify the type of T, because of generic erasure，

```
fun main() {
  val className = object:GernericClass<SomeObjectClass>(){}
  className.printOut()  
}
```

```
  fun printOut() {
        val clazz =
            (this.javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<*>
        println(clazz) // I want something like this
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, can you explain to me the object:GernericClass<SomeObjectClass>(){}. I'm a little bit lost in this line. If you have some link that I can read it from then it will be very useful. Thanks you

Comment: The generic objects themselves are just the raw type, the parameterized type is "erased"
So, need a subclass to specify the type of T.    object:GernericClass<SomeObjectClass>(){}// anonymous class