# Kotlin get type of generic class without instance

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I want go get `Type` of `T`, but I can not get it from instance. I have to get it from class parameter, how to do it?

```
abstract class ViewModelFragment<T : ViewModel>{
    protected lateinit var mViewModel: T

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       mViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                    .of(scope)
                    .get(getGenericTClass())
    // .get(mViewModel.javaClass) // not working either

   }

   inline fun<reified R> getGenericTClass() = R::class.java

}
```

Right now compiler complains

> Cannot use 'T' as refined class type. Use Class instead.

I've tried to use solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463352/2163045) but it's not working for me

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and the code below helped me:

```
val persistentClass = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<T>
mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelsFactory).get(persistentClass)
```